# How do I fix the Bundle installation rejected by hook on AEM 6.1

Tags: maven, aem

I have been trying to build  this bundle from Maven, it fails. Even manually trying to upload from the felix console  doesn't help. I tried removing the jar from the install location under/apps/project/install and redeploy. But no Luck. Below is the stack trace . Same one used to work in earlier builds.

Any help would be appreciated

```
13.10.2016 22:42:08.624 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.tasks.BundleInstallTask Exception during install of bundle TaskResource(url=jcrinstall:/apps/octoberadvanced/install/advanced.core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, entity=bundle:october.advanced.core, state=INSTALL, attributes=[org.apache.sling.installer.api.tasks.ResourceTransformer=:94:21:, Bundle-SymbolicName=october.advanced.core, Bundle-Version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT], digest=1476378728376) : Bundle installation rejected by hook.. Retrying later.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle installation rejected by hook.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3045)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.tasks.BundleInstallTask.execute(BundleInstallTask.java:47)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.OsgiInstallerImpl.executeTasks(OsgiInstallerImpl.java:735)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.OsgiInstallerImpl.run(OsgiInstallerImpl.java:249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have any other bundle with same name or same bundle already deployed?

Comment: @AmeeshTrikha : No  its a first time deploy of my maven project.

Comment: @AmeeshTrikha, I am having the same issue. But I do have the same bundle in my system folder with a different version. Is there is a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

I haved tried all of things. And in the end this is what worked for me.

- I went to the install folder of my bundle say /apps/myproject/install and deleted it.
- Then I went to /system/console/bundles and saw that my bundles was still showing there even after deleting it. So I deleted it from the bundles console as well.
- And finally I did a fresh maven build. And everything works.

**Conclusion: That was a stale bundle. You just need to get rid of that fully and install a fresh one!!**

Might not work for you. But this is worth a try.